# CodeLite 12.0.2 : nothing in Editor

Tags: editor, codelite

I wondered if anyone could help me with a strange bug I am having with CodeLite, which I am using as C IDE.

Basically nothing displays in the right side window editor when I open source files.  This also happens when trying to change the fonts etc (this is where i looked first), whereby no preview displays.

Of possible note, that this absence of displayed text also occurs for example texts such as the one during the set up, as well as the pop up "Colours and Fonts".

The rest seems to work correctly, I was able to compile and run a project in the workspace for which I knew no edits needed to be made.

I am running Windows 7 professional 64 bits and i have not observed any issue elsewhere, only with CodeLite. I used the 64 bits installer to install CodeLite 12.02.

Attempted so far: restart computer, uninstall / reinstall CodeLite. Obviously looked up google, stackoverflow and CodeLite forum, without success finding anything similar.

Any idea where I should look for ways to solve this issue ?

Screenshot of CodeLite with a an example main.c open in editor but not showing content:
[image: Screenshot of CodeLite with a an example main.c open]

Screenshot of actual content of example main.c (hello world):
[image: Screenshot of actual content of example main.c (hello world)]

Screenshot of CodeLite initial set up, also showing no example text:
[image: Screenshot of CodeLite initial set up, also showing no example text]

Screenshot of CodeLite "Colours and Fonts" pop up, also showing no example text:
[image: Screenshot of CodeLite "Colours and Fonts" pop up, also showing no example text]

Comment: A screenshot would be great to understand what you mean...

Comment: I have just added screenshots and more details, hopefully that will help.

Comment: Try this: Close CodeLite, and then delete the folder: %appdata%\CodeLite. This seems to be an installation problem or some corrupted files issue

Comment: Would a fresh install have the same effect ? I have already uninstalled and  reinstalled a few times.

Comment: Ok I have tried that anyway and the bug is still there.

Comment: What happens when you install CodeLite 12.0 (the stable version)? Does it work for you?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue and result with version 12.0. I have just uninstalled 12.0.2 and installed 12.0 to make sure this was still the case.

Answer (score 1):

May be it's late, but it happened that I solved the issue. I experienced the same problem with the latest CodeLite v15.0.3 at the time of writing. I also have Windows 7 64 bits and nothing was shown for the text of any opened source file.

Solution:

Open Settings > Preferences > Misc

and simply uncheck this setting:

[ ] Windows Only: use Direct2D editor drawings

It helped me.